# How to resize an image but keep pixel's value with python

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm dealing with some images, and I'd like to resize them from 1080 * 1920 to 480 * 640. *I have classified every single pixel into a specific class so each of them has a unique value.* However, those value of pixel would changed if I resized image.

```
python
resized = cv2.resize(image, (640, 480), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
print(set(resized.flat)) --> a dict {0,1,2,3,4……,38,39,40}
print(set(image.flat)) --> a dict {0,10,40}

# image size is 1080 * 1920
# resized size is 480 * 640

desired_image = cv2.imread(desired_image_path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).astype(np.uint8)
print(set(desired_image.flat)) --> a dict {0,10,40}

# desired_image size is 480 * 640
```

I expect to have the desired image which have the size of 480 * 640 without any crop and keep the pixel's value same. Now I have the correct size but value of pixels change a lot.

Comment: If you resize an image to a lower resolution (or physical size) then the current one, you could not expect to preserve the same pixel values as the previous image. Reason? Simply because there doesn't exists enough pixels to store data. The only way you could preserve the original pixels (only some of them) is via cropping. As we can crop to a lower size, where the pixels of that regions will be preserved from the original image.

Comment: good explanation!:) Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you want to resize the image without creating new pixel values. This can be done by setting the `interpolation` parameter of `cv2.resize` to `INTER_NEAREST`

```
resized = cv2.resize(image, (640, 480), interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

Source: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize

Comment: Thanks! Could you give some example images?